# Heroku Api call returning 403 - FortiGuard

Tags: node.js, heroku, post

I have an API deployed at Heroku, it should receive notifications from a Payment Gateway.It is a Post request (PagSeguro from Brazil). Checking the logs every time they try to send an update on payment status they get a 403 from FortiGuard.

Don't know if this is from Heroku side's or PagSeguro's.

Can anyone give me a little help?

Comment: Isn't FortiGuard an application firewall? Are you using the default `.herokuapp.com` domain, and do they have rules that prevent requests to such domains from going through? That wouldn't surprise me, as lots of phishing sites are hosted on Heroku.

Comment: @Chris I believe this the case, I tried from herokuapp.com, also tried fowarding to my domain, but Fortiguard tracks the DNS, so they see heroku anyways. Looks like they are blocking connection with heroku.

Comment: Then whoever is using FortiGuard, which is probably whoever is trying to hit your site (PagSeguro?), needs to change the rules they subscribe to. See if they're willing to whitelist your site.